# Ubuntu App Development for Desktop

Tags: application-development

I wish to start App Development in Ubuntu for Desktop. However, in the website for Ubuntu Development, i find information related only to phone development.
The Ubuntu SDK - can it be used for desktop app development too???

Answer (score 3):

The SDK can be used for desktop development, that is part of the overall convergence strategy that Ubuntu is taking.  You can run any app written with the Ubuntu SDK on your desktop or Ubuntu Touch device.

At the moment, the SDK works better for mobile touch-enabled apps than for desktop keyboard and mouse enabled ones, but there is work already underway to improve it on the desktop.

Comment: Could you explain how to export the application written in the Ubuntu SDK for desktop? Currently, the closest I can get is `cd`ing to the build directory and running `qmlscene Main.qml`. I'd like the app to be visible in the Dash with the icon I made and I'm yet to find any documentation that explains how to achieve this.

Comment: Correction: the closest I've gotten is manually putting absolute paths to the QML scene and icon in the `.desktop` file and then copying it to `/usr/share/applications`